# How to get the width and height of my image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my image width and height by using the following code but all I receive is undefined.

Can anyone explain to me how this work?

```
<script>
var img = new Image();
img = document.getElementById("top");
alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
</script>
<body>
    <div id="ad">
        <div id="banner">
            <img class="top" id="top" src="frame_2.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think `this` is.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to write `this`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/623172/135978) for alternative ways of getting the information, depending on what version of "width" and "height" you are interested in.

Answer (score 5):

First, if you're getting the image from the document, you don't need to call `new Image`.

You *do* need to wait until the `img` element exists, and until the `img` loads.

That's easiest if you add the image with the script, and hook the `load` event **before** setting `src`:

```
<body>
    <div id="ad">
        <div id="banner"></div>
    </div>
<script>
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.className = "top";
img.id = "top";
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
};
img.src="frame_2.jpg";
document.getElementById("banner").appendChild(img);
</script>
</body>
```

You *can* do it with the image in the HTML, though, you just have to allow for the possibility the image may have *already* loaded before you hooked the event:

```
<body>
    <div id="ad">
        <div id="banner">
            <img class="top" id="top" src="frame_2.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
var img = document.getElementById("top");
img.onload = loaded;
if (img.complete) {
    loaded();
}
function loaded() {
  if (img) {
      alert(img.width + 'x' + img.height);
      img.onload = null;
      img = null; // Just as a marker in case of repeated calls
  }
};
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` will most probably point to `Window` in that case. Try `img.width` and `img.height` instead.

Comment: or `img.clientWidth` and `img.clientHeight` if you want the responsive height and widths.

Comment: Not to mention the superfluous `new Image()` and not waiting for the image to render, much less load. Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
img = document.getElementById("top");
img.onload = function() {
  alert(img.width + 'x' + img.height);
};
```

```html
    <div id="ad">
        <div id="banner">
            <img class="top" id="top" src="http://fpoimg.com/300x300"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Worth noting that the script tag needs to come *after* the `img` or else wait for `DOMContentReady` (otherwise `getElementById` will return `null`).

Comment: This will be a race the code will sometimes lose, particularly if the image is in cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`.

```
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

See [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an *instance of Image* if later you re-assign that variable with an element queried on the DOM...

By the way, you need to wait the Dom Ready or Window Loaded (indicated for media objects) event...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var img = document.querySelector('.my-image');

  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = img.width + ' x ' + img.height;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>

<img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" class="my-image" />
```

Comment: Need to add `img.onload` and do your write there - the image hasn't necessarily loaded when `DOMContentLoaded` fires. (I see `0 x 0` in the example right now).

Comment: As I worte below, for media-objects (such as images, videos, ecc.) the window.onload event is more correct...

If you attach an event to a single image this doesn't work with more images... the global window event works fine!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get my image width and height by using the following code but all I receive is undefined.

This because you try to select the image in the DOM **before** it has been created.

If you want to get image dimensions you can do many ways. If you want simply check them you can do **inline**:

```
<body>
    <div id="ad">
        <div id="banner">
            <img class="top" id="top" src="frame_2.jpg" onload="console.log(this.width + ' x ' + this.height + ' px');"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS and other style - may change result of question.

Use attributes: **naturalWidth** and **naturalHeight**

They give correct imagesize.

Answer (score -2):

Why not to try simple jQuery?

```
var imageWidth = $('#top').width();
var imageHeight = $('#top').height();
alert(imageWidth + 'x' + imageHeight);
```

Comment: Because it's overkill for this task.

Comment: And moreover, if the OP just plops this where their current code is, it'll fail (for two different reasons).